# How to overclock an ATI/AMD graphic card further than Overdrive allows?

Tags: graphics-card, overclocking

I've got a fresh HD 6850 overclocked to 850 MHz with OverDrive.

I heard its possible to run it at 1000 MHz but how?

Please don't educate me about the risks of overclocking!

Comment: This requires modification of the video BIOS.  There are several utilities that can be used to do this, including [ATIFlash and ATI Winflash](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/Utilities/BIOS_Flashing/ATI/).

Comment: Why don't you post this as an answer?
Will the video BIOS void my guarantee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires modification of the video BIOS. There are several utilities that can be used to do this, including [ATIFlash and ATI Winflash](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/Utilities/BIOS_Flashing/ATI/).  As this operation involves a low-level modification of the card firmware, if this is done incorrectly, the card will not be covered under warranty if a failure occurs.  There are several guides online about this process; you may want to look at this rather outdated [techPowerUp article on flashing the video BIOS](http://www.techpowerup.com/articles/overclocking/vidcard/34).

Answer (score 0):

I just read it's also possible using MSI Afterburner by enabling unofficial overclocking in the config-file. (It works even without a MSI-card).